# set desktop font via command line and without gnome-settings-daemon?

Tags: command-line, fonts

i've switched from unity to i3wm and i'm really enjoying it
however there is a slight problem: i can't set the desired `desktop font` without running gnome-settings-daemon. and at the moment this is the only reason for running it.

for the gtk apps i can set the font i like in `.gtkrc-2.0` but that doesn't have any effect on the fonts appearing in the menus, dialogs, etc.

what i actually want is the same effect as `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Roboto 10'` gets but this only works if `gnome-settings-daemon` is running. also i tried to replace DejaVu Sans with Roboto using `.fonts.conf` but that didn't work as well.

this is driving me nuts since weeks so i'd just like to know is it possible at all? maybe i shall have a look at `.Xresources` or something? otherwise i guess i'll just have to replace the font files themselves to reach the goal.

thx in advance for any help.

ps. 12.04 and 13.04 no luck on either.

Comment: okay if anybody's interested i've finally found a solution, it works at least in 13.04. for applets' menus such as network manager it is enough to set `gtk-font-name` in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`. for other menus and prompts i've set preferred `sans` font in `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`. it works!

Answer (score -1):

Desktop font : the font for icon name on the desktop

gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop font 'Sans 8'